# How do I make the closest future date to today's date the default dropdownlist value?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

We dynamically populate our dropdownlist with several event dates from the database.

Currently, all dates less than today's date are disabled and can't be viewed by our users.

The next available date greater than today's date becomes the default dropdownlist value and all future dates are avaiable and visible in the dropdownlist.

For instance, if we have the following dates on our datebase:

2/12/2013

12/20/203

5/21/2014

8/8/2014

10/22/2014

since three of the dates (**2/12/2013,12/20/203,5/21/2014**) are less than today's date, these dates are disabled and not viewable.

The closest available date greater than today's date is 8/8/2014 and this becomes the default dropdownlist value.

Finally all future dates like 10/22/2014 are also available in the dropdownlist.

Here are the code snips that make this happen:

//the markup

```
  <asp:DropDownList id="txtEventDate" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

//Code that dynamically populates dropdownlist

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select convert(datetime, dates, 103) dates, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dates, 107) as datelist from events", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Events").ConnectionString))
          cmd.Connection.Open()

          Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
          ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

          txtEventDate.DataSource = ddlValues
          txtEventDate.DataValueField = "dates"
          txtEventDate.DataTextField = "datelist"
          txtEventDate.DataBind()

          cmd.Connection.Close()
              cmd.Connection.Dispose()
```

//Code that displays only future dates with next available future date as default dropdownlist value

```
For Each items As ListItem In txtEventDate.Items
    If (DateTime.Parse(items.Value).CompareTo(DateTime.Today)) < 0 Then
        items.Enabled = False
    End If
Next
```

Our users would like to change the process so they would be allowed to go back to an older date and make some changes if they needed to.

Any ideas how to address this problem?

```
Public Sub PopulateDates()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select convert(datetime, dates, 103) dates, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dates, 107) as datelist from events", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("events").ConnectionString))
    cmd.Connection.Open()


    Dim lstDates As New List(Of DateTime)()

    Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If rdr.Read() Then
            lstDates.Add(DirectCast(rdr("dates"), DateTime))
        End If
    End Using

    lstDates = lstDates.OrderBy(Function(x) x.[Date]).ToList()
    Dim nearestDate = lstDates.OrderBy(Function(t) Math.Abs((t - DateTime.Now).Ticks)).First()
    txtEventDate.DataSource = lstDates
    txtEventDate.DataBind()
    txtEventDate.SelectedIndex = txtEventDate.Items.IndexOf(txtEventDate.Items.FindByValue(nearestDate.ToString()))

    cmd.Connection.Close()
    cmd.Connection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your title of the question and the last line (`Our users would like to change the process so they would be allowed to go back to an older date and make some changes if they needed to`) contradicts. Do you want to disable the older dates or provide the user to change it?

Comment: @DennisR, sorry. That's exactly what I was trying to avoid.

We want to display all the available dates but show the date closest to the current date as dropdownlist default value.

Yes, this allows the users the ability to select a different, albeit older date to make changes based on that date.

For instance, if an event ocurred on 01/01/2014 and they wish to make changes based on that date, they should be able to select that date. However, the closest date to current date remains the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your comment it seems like you want to let the user change the older dates. So remove your `For Each` that disables the older dates.

First you need to find the nearest date equal or closer to current date like below

```
Dim nearestDate = ddlValues.OrderBy(Function(t) Math.Abs((t.dates - DateTime.Now).Ticks)).First()
```

Then after you do the data binding keep the nearest date default selected using `FindByValue` or `FindByText`

```
txtEventDate.SelectedIndex = txtEventDate.Items.IndexOf(txtEventDate.Items.FindByValue(nearestDate.ToString()))
```

***Side Note:*** always try using `using` statements for your db connection objects like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommad` etc so the resources used by these objects are freed up after usage.

**UPDATE 1:** Based on what you reported in your comment, I made few changes as to the date format ( it was not part of your initial question) etc and here is the complete code for `PopulateDates()`. Also make sure you don't run the `foreach` you earlier had to set the nearest date because it might set wrong values. If you get wrong values then better put breakpoint and see which object returns unexpected data.

```
Public Sub PopulateDates()
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select dates from events", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("events").ConnectionString))
  cmd.Connection.Open()

  Dim lstDates As New List(Of DateTime)()

  Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      If rdr.Read() Then
          lstDates.Add(DirectCast(rdr("dates"), DateTime))
      End If
  End Using

    Dim stDates As List(Of [String]) = lstDates.OrderBy(Function(o) o.[Date]).[Select](Function(x) x.[Date].ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")).ToList()
    Dim nearestDate = lstDates.OrderBy(Function(t) Math.Abs((t - DateTime.Now).Ticks)).First()
    // Dim nearestDate = lstDates.First(Function(x) x >= DateTime.Now.[Date]) // this does the trick too

    txtEventDate.DataSource = stDates
    txtEventDate.DataBind()
    txtEventDate.SelectedIndex = txtEventDate.Items.IndexOf(txtEventDate.Items.FindByValue(nearestDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")))

  cmd.Connection.Close()
  cmd.Connection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Here is the link to the **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/QxFXAB)** (unfortunately it's in C#) I set up to show how it return me the correct data.

**UPDATE 2:** Here is your complete working version (hopefully it works). I tried this locally to load the data from database and retrieving through the `DataReader` and everything works the way you wanted.

You reported in your comment saying only one item was returned when accessing from the DataReader, it's because your original code had `If rdr.Read() Then` which will exit after the first record but rather we    need to use `while` to iterate the complete list.

Regarding `Value` field and `Text` of the dropdownlist holding different date format, I've created a `Dictionary` collection to achieve this. Here is your complete code for `PopulateDates()`.

```
Public Sub PopulateDates()
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select dates from events order by dates", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("events").ConnectionString))
  cmd.Connection.Open()

  Dim list As New Dictionary(Of String, DateTime)()

  Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     Dim dt As DateTime
     While rdr.Read()
        dt = DateTime.Parse(rdr("dates").ToString())
        list.Add(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), dt)
     End While
  End Using

  txtEventDate.DataSource = list
  txtEventDate.DataTextField = "Value"
  txtEventDate.DataValueField = "key"
  txtEventDate.DataTextFormatString = "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}"
  txtEventDate.DataBind()

  Dim nearestDate = list.First(Function(x) x.Value >= DateTime.Now.[Date]).Key
  txtEventDate.SelectedIndex = txtEventDate.Items.IndexOf(txtEventDate.Items.FindByValue(nearestDate.ToString()))

  cmd.Connection.Close()
  cmd.Connection.Dispose()

End Sub
```

And the HTML markup looks like the format you wanted.

[image]

Comment: @DennisR, Now I need a drink. Numerous issues but I have worked them down to just one that says, `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first`

I don't want to dump too much code here for fear of enraging someone but I have posted the latest code I am working with.

I did try to close the reader but I am afraid something else is going on.

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh :) Sorry..I'm back from my lunch. The error says it all. There are more than one `cmd.ExecuteReader()` in your updated code. As I said in my `Update 1` edit `lstDates` collection has everything you need to bind to the dropdown so you can remove `ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()` in your code and the next four lines of databinding code. Let me know I can make one more edit with the complete code for your sub `PopulateDates`

Comment: @DennisR, sorry I had already left before your last post.

I made the changes you recommended (I think). Now, the error is gone but there are two issues.

1, it is displaying just one date and it is not the correct date. Infact, it is displaying date ealier than todays' date.

2, the text should display Mon dd, yyyy. Example:

Jan 23, 2014.

I have updated my code so you can see what I am still doing wrong.

By the way, Mark, if you are still following us, your code does not produce the closest future date to today's date like we wanted.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh No problem. See my edit. If you're seeing unexpected result please put break point and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: @DennisR, thanks a lot for your help. I am about to test it now. As for the date format not being in my original question, I didn't explicitly state that requirement because the code I posted was already doing that. For instance, this code `convert(datetime, dates, 103) dates', gives date format of MM/dd/yyyy and that is the value for the dropdownlist. However, the date format that shows in text is this code: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dates, 107) as datelist` and it displays as Jan 01, 2014 or MMM dd, yyyy. I thought that was obvious. Sorry about that.

Comment: @DennisR, this is the result your code is producing: `<option value="Jul 31, 2012">Jul 31, 2012</option>` This is not correct. Infact, there are still two issues: 1, the results should be in the following format: `<option value="7/31/2012">Jul 31, 2012</option>` As you can see, Value has MM/dd/yyyy and Text has MMM dd, yyyy. 2, it is not displaying the next available future date closest to today's date. In our db, that should have been `8/8/2014`. Finally, ALL dates, past present and future should also be in the dropdownlist so users can select them if they wish too. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ChidiOkeh I am not sure why do you need different date format one for `Value` and other for `Text`. If it's your need to get the selected value from the dropdown to send it to db for update in `(MM/dd/yyyy)` format then you can convert the selected value like `DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(txtEventDate.SelectedValue);` and
 `string dateInSpecficFormat = myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`. As for as not displaying the next available future date closest to today's date you will have to put breakpoint and check the value returned for `Dim nearestDate`.

Comment: Did you look at my [demo](http://ideone.com/QxFXAB)? It returns the closest future date to current date and displays all futures dates too like what you wanted.

Comment: @DennisR, I did take a look at your demo.

I think I know why your solution is returning only one date. 

In our db, we have the dates as MM/dd/yyyy. So, in the VALUE portion of the dropdownlist, your code is populating that dropdown VALUE as MMM dd, yyyy same as it is populating the TEXT portion of the dropdownlist.

I hope I am making sense to you.

So, if it at all possible to modify your code to populate the dropdownlist with date value in the format of MM/dd/yyyy, while leaving the text part of the dropdownlist just like it is now, I think it will start working.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: @ChidiOkeh, sorry for the delay, got busy with my project. Look at UPDATE 2: I'm sure this time it should work.

Comment: @DennisR, BAM!!!

That did the trick. It is working beautifully. 

Thank you so much for your patience and persistence. 

Your great assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Totally untested, but would something like the following do what you want?  Your list of items will need to be sorted, if it's not already, but this should find the first item that is for today or later and set it as the selected item in the drop-down.

**Update** - try `SelectedValue` instead!

```vb
For Each items As ListItem In txtEventDate.Items
    If (DateTime.Parse(items.Value).CompareTo(DateTime.Today)) >= 0 Then
        txtEventDate.SelectedValue = items.Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```